# Does "After" in a systemd unit affects the order in shutdown or reboot

Tags: systemd

I have a service that is set to start after network like so:

```
[Unit]
Description=Some service
After=network.target
```

The service itself runs find and does what it supposed to do. But when I issue a reboot command, the systemd will say something like:

```
A stopjob is running for "SERVICE"...
```

And a default timeout will be passed before the service is really terminated.

If I remove the "After" clause, the service runs normally again and I do not get the timeout anymore when trying to reboot.

I was wondering what could be the reason? Does the "After" also means the service should be terminated or stopped before or after the given target? I Mean does it affect in any way the order of stopping too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was too quick with my question. The systemd manpage clearly says:

> Note that when two units with an ordering dependency between them are shut down, the inverse of the start-up order is applied. i.e. if a unit is configured with After= on another unit, the former is stopped before the latter if both are shut down. Given two units with any ordering dependency between them, if one unit is shut down and the other is started up, the shutdown is ordered before the start-up. It doesn't matter if the ordering dependency is After= or Before=.